# Get tables from AWS Glue using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, boto3, aws-glue

I need to harvest tables and column names from AWS Glue crawler metadata catalogue. I used `boto3` but constantly getting number of 100 tables even though there are more. Setting up `NextToken` doesn't help. Please help if possible.

Desired results is list as follows:

lst = [table_one.col_one, table_one.col_two, table_two.col_one....table_n.col_n]

```
def harvest_aws_crawler():
glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name='')
response = glue.get_tables(DatabaseName='', NextToken = '')

#response syntax:
#https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_tables
crawler_list_tables = []

for tables in response['TableList']:
    while (response.get('NextToken') is not None):
        crawler_list_tables.append(tables['Name'])
        break
print(len(crawler_list_tables))

harvest_aws_crawler()
```

UPDATED code, still need to have tablename+columnname:

```
def harvest_aws_crawler():
glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name='')
next_token = ""

#response syntax:
#https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_tables
response = glue.get_tables(DatabaseName='', NextToken = next_token)

tables_from_crawler = []
while True:
    table_list = response['TableList']
    for table_dict in table_list:
        table_name = table_dict['Name']
        
        #append table_name+column_name
        for columns in table_name['StorageDescriptor']['Columns']:
            tables_from_crawler.append(table_name + '.' + columns['Name'])
                
        #tables_from_crawler.append(table_name)
    next_token = response.get('NextToken')
    if next_token is None:
        break
print(tables_from_crawler)

harvest_aws_crawler()
```

Comment: You do not use the `NextToken` for the next request, otherwise you will always get the first 100. Or use the paginator for get_tables: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html

Comment: @luk2302 - thank you but still I'm getting 100 tables while using `get_paginator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding sub-loop did the trick to get table+column result.

```
#harvest aws crawler metadata
next_token = ""
client = boto3.client('glue',region_name='us-east-1')
crawler_tables = []

while True:
  response = client.get_tables(DatabaseName = '', NextToken = next_token)
  for tables in response['TableList']:
    for columns in tables['StorageDescriptor']['Columns']:
        crawler_tables.append(tables['Name'] + '.' + columns['Name'])
  next_token = response.get('NextToken')
  if next_token is None:
    break
print(crawler_tables)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below approach by using the `paginator` option:

```
def get_tables_for_database(database):
    starting_token = None
    next_page = True
    tables = []
    while next_page:
        paginator = glue_client.get_paginator(operation_name="get_tables")
        response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            DatabaseName=database,
            PaginationConfig={"PageSize": 100, "StartingToken": starting_token},
        )
        for elem in response_iterator:
            tables += [
                {
                    "name": table["Name"],
                }
                for table in elem["TableList"]
            ]
            try:
                starting_token = elem["NextToken"]
            except:
                next_page = False
    return tables
```

and then do invoke the method to list out the tables for a given database:

```
for table in get_tables_for_database(database):
        print(f"Table: {table['name']}")
```

If you want to list the tables for every database out there in Glue, you may have to do an additional for loop in order to retrieve the databases first, and then extract the tables using the above snippet as your inner loop for each database.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to get tablename with it's column names?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MaxResults`

```
response = glue.get_tables(DatabaseName='', NextToken = '', MaxResults = number_that_greater_than_your_actual_tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tables = list(dynamodb_resource.tables.all())` worked for me. And if I need only names in my script, additionally I use `table_name = tables_names[x].name`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).